# TimelinePlot with many intervals becomes white

Tags: plotting

This is an example of a TimelinePlot with 100 intervals:

```
TimelinePlot[Table[Interval[{0, 1}], {30}], 
             PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

[image: timeline with 100 lines]

If we increase the number of intervals to 300, they seem to dissapper:

```
TimelinePlot[Table[Interval[{0, 1}], {300}], 
             PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

[image: timeline with 300 lines becomes invisible]

I know that the lines are still there, but they seem to have a white border or something else that makes them virtually disappear when they are very close to each other. Is there any way to make these lines visible?

Note: I know that in this simplified example, if all lines are shown, we will get a solid rectangle. In my real application, I have hundreds of intervals chronologically close but not exactly on top of each other.

**UDTADE**:
It was suggested to change the `AspectRatio` but this is not a solution as it just increases the number of intervals needed to blank out the output. I am looking for a way to eliminate the blanking altogether. Ohh wait...  While writing this I realized that the blanking is caused by `GrayLevel[1]` elements and apparently it happens to be possible to remove them without undesired collateral damage:

```
TimelinePlot[Table[Interval[{0, 1}], {30}], 
             PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"] /. GrayLevel[1] -> Nothing
```

[image]

```
TimelinePlot[Table[Interval[{0, 1}], {300}], 
             PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"] /. GrayLevel[1] -> Nothing
```

[image]

While this solved my problem, it is a hackish workaround as I think that the appearance should be changed with options. I'll leave the question open in case someone knows how to do this with options or at least a less fragile way of achieving this.

Comment: Set the `AspectRatio` to `1` or higher

Answer (score 2):

I was not intending to answer my own question, but I found a way to solve this good enough to be shared.

The blanking element can be seen easily using the `ReadableForm` resource function with a minimal case:

```
ResourceFunction["ReadableForm"][
 TimelinePlot[Interval[{0, 1}], PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]]
```

In the output below I added a comment indicating the problematic white line that needs to be removed:

```
Graphics[
    {
        {
            Opacity[ 0 ],
            AbsolutePointSize[ 0 ],
            Point @ { { 0., 1 }, { 1., 3 / 2 } },
            Point @ { { 0., -1 / 2 }, { 1., 0 } }
        },
        { },
        {
            { Opacity[ 0 ], PointSize[ 0 ], Point @ { { 0., 1 }, { 1., 1 } } },
            {
                {
                    Directive[
                        AbsolutePointSize[ 7 ],
                        RGBColor[ 0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798 ],
                        AbsoluteThickness[ 1.6 ],
                        Opacity[ 1 ]
                    ],
                    {
                        {
                            Directive @ Opacity[ 0.2 ],
                            {
                                Directive @ Opacity[ 0.2 ],
                                EdgeForm[ ],
                                Rectangle[ { 0., 1 }, { 1., 1 } ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            { },
                            {
                                {
                                    {
                                        { },
                                        {
                                            {
                                                { (****** This is the problematic white line ******)
                                                    GrayLevel[ 1 ],
                                                    AbsoluteThickness[ 2 ],
                                                    Line @ {
                                                        {
                                                            Offset[
                                                                { 0, -1 },
                                                                { 0., 1 }
                                                            ],
                                                            Offset[
                                                                { 0, -1 },
                                                                { 1., 1 }
                                                            ]
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                            Offset[
                                                                { 0, 1 },
                                                                { 0., 1 }
                                                            ],
                                                            Offset[
                                                                { 0, 1 },
                                                                { 1., 1 }
                                                            ]
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    AbsolutePointSize[ 10 ],
                                                    GrayLevel[ 1 ],
                                                    Point @ { { 0., 1 }, { 1., 1 } }
                                                },
                                                Point @ { { 0., 1 }, { 1., 1 } },
                                                Line @ { { 0., 1 }, { 1., 1 } }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        { },
                                        {
                                            {
                                                AbsolutePointSize[ 4 ],
                                                GrayLevel[ 1 ],
                                                Point @ { { 0., 1 }, { 1., 1 } }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    { }
                                },
                                { { }, { } }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            { { { { } }, { } } }
        },
        { },
        { }
    },
    PlotRange -> { { All, All }, { 0, All } },
    ImagePadding -> All,
    PlotRangePadding -> { { Scaled[ 0.08 ], Scaled[ 0.08 ] }, { None, Scaled[ 0.05 ] } },
    AspectRatio -> 1 / 20,
    Axes -> { False, False },
    Frame -> { { None, None }, { True, None } },
    FrameTicks -> {
        { None, None },
        {
            Function[
                Charting`getDateTicks[
                    Automatic,
                    { Automatic },
                    (DateList /@ { ##1 } &)[ ##1 ],
                    None,
                    7,
                    { { 0.01, 0 }, { 0.005, 0 } },
                    Automatic
                ]
            ],
            Automatic
        }
    },
    Ticks -> {
        {
            { -1., "23:59:59", { 0.006666666666666666, 0 } },
            { 0., "00:00:00", { 0.006666666666666666, 0 } },
            { 1., "00:00:01", { 0.006666666666666666, 0 } },
            { 2., "00:00:02", { 0.006666666666666666, 0 } },
            { -1., Spacer @ { 0, 0 }, { 0.006666666666666666, 0 } },
            { 0., Spacer @ { 0, 0 }, { 0.006666666666666666, 0 } },
            { 1., Spacer @ { 0, 0 }, { 0.006666666666666666, 0 } }
        },
        None
    },
    AxesOrigin -> { 0, 0 },
    {
        Axes -> Automatic,
        GridLines -> { None, None },
        ImageSize -> { 600, Automatic }
    }
]
```

In order to remove the while lines we use this pattern: `{GrayLevel[1], AbsoluteThickness[2], Line[_]}`. Also, for large number of intervals, the dots in the boundary of each interval are unnecessary and even problematic as they too have white inside. So this produces clean a output:

```
TimelinePlot[Table[Interval[{0, 1}], {300}], 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"] /. {
        {GrayLevel[1], AbsoluteThickness[2], Line[_]} -> Nothing,
         Point[_] -> Nothing}
```

[image: corrected timeline with 300 intervals]

Let's conclude with a more realistic example. Without the fix the bars below are very hard to see:

```
data = Table[NestList[# + Quantity[RandomInteger[{0, 2}], "Hours"] &, DateInterval[Today], 300], {5}];
TimelinePlot[data, PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[1], PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

[image]

The presented solution greatly improves the visibility of the bars:

```
TimelinePlot[data, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
  PlotStyle -> 
   AbsoluteThickness[1]] /. {{GrayLevel[ 1 ], AbsoluteThickness[ 2 ], 
    Line[_]} -> Nothing, Point[_] -> Nothing}
```

[image]